# Install Jenkins plugins Offline

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins, offline

I have a server running Jenkins which has not connectivity to the internet what so ever. Not through a proxy, nothing.

I have to install a bunch of plugins with all of their dependencies. What would be the simplest way of doing this? It would take forever to manually download the .hpi files and install them...

Could I get creative and run Jenkins on my PC, install all the needed plugins and then copy that plugin folder to my server or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work. Copy the content in your $JENKINS_HOME directory to the other Jenkins server. Plugins are stored in $JENKINS_HOME/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It will work.

The only thing that needs to be copied is the jpi/hpi files in the `/plugins` directory.

Jenkins expands the plugins into same named directories within. Up restart, initial configuration files are created in the `${JENKINS_HOME}` directory or added to `config.xml`.

If you don't perform any configuration locally you need not copy the configs.

Note, once installed locally (and restarted so operational), you can get a full list of plugins installed from the `/systemInfo`. When installing a plugin it will download the latest listed but also the latest compatible dependencies, which may change at any time, so you may not get the same set 2nd time.

You can use the list to know what's been updated from time to time, or just click **Update All** and then can find plugins (jpi/hpi) w/newer time stamps and copy those over later.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I just copied my $JENKINS_HOME/plugins from my PC with a bunch of plugins installed through http://127.0.0.1:8080/pluginManager/available to my RHEL 7.3.

Although $JENKINS_HOME/plugins on my RHEL server is full off plugins:
bash-4.2$ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/plugins
bash-4.2$ ls -alt
total 28
drwxrwxrwx.   5 jenkins jenkins   64 Jun 20 09:15 ws-cleanup
etc etc..

The Jenkins GUI isn't showing any when browsing to /pluginManager/installed.

Also, I cant find any .hpi or .jpi in the plugins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure where the jpi went, but `drwxrwxrwx` are the exploded jpi (jar) files, one dirextory per plugin, named same as the plugin, minus extension. If it shows no plugins in UI and no jpi, maybe they got removed? The exploded ones should have been wiped too. If the only thing left is WA-cleanup, perhaps a misconfigured job wiped the plugins director, except for the ws-cleanup, which would have been in active use so can't be deleted. Check system logs for hints.